# Angular 2 RC5 http error handling

Tags: http, angular, typescript, webpack, zone

I am new in Angular 2, in my Angular 2 project I create API call service that return json data.

```
this._http.post(this.url,  body, options)
                         .map(response => response.json())
                         .catch(this.handleError);
```

Let say this service return 401 Http Response unauthorized and I tried get the status error, so I can redirect to Login Page and show error message

```
.subscribe(
        login => this.login=login,
        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
```

but why response code did not throw as error, and only show result 
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)` and end the task ?

when I debug the code, the result generated in this line code

```
this.invoke = function () {
                try {
                    return zone.runTask(self, this, arguments);
                }
                finally {
                    drainMicroTaskQueue();
                }
            };
        }
```

any suggestion ?

Thank You